# SQL USING AND , OR COMBINATION

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle 10g. In the form there are 3 fields:

```
from date
To date 
Customer
```

I have a table with `customer`,`delivery no` and `date`. i want to show a report with the following condition:

1. User can either give `from` and `to date` - then it shows all details             irrespective of `customer` name
2. User can give only `customer` name - then it shows details based on `customer` irrespective of date
3. User can give `from date`,`to date` and `customer` - then it shows details of `customer` with in that particular date

I have to show report based on these condition how to write that query.

From the form I will pass the values to the report builder

```
SELECT  A.DEL_NO,
        A.DEL_DATE, 
        A.CONS_ADDR
FROM    ITBG_DELCHELLAN A
where   A.oano is null
and     A.DEL_date between :sdate and :edate 
OR      UPPER(A.cons_addr) like '%'||:adr||'%';
```

where `sdate` is `from date`, `edate` is `to date` and `adr` is `customer`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```sql
SELECT  A.DEL_NO,
        A.DEL_DATE, 
        A.CONS_ADDR
FROM    ITBG_DELCHELLAN A
WHERE   A.oano is null
AND     ( :sdate IS NULL OR :edate IS NULL OR A.DEL_date BETWEEN :sdate AND :edate )
AND     ( :adr IS NULL OR UPPER(A.cons_addr) LIKE '%'||:adr||'%' )
-- Prevent returning everything if neither option is given.
AND     ( ( :sdate IS NOT NULL AND :edate IS NOT NULL ) OR :adr IS NOT NULL )
```